# Can we make a table having both partitioning and bucketing in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Can we make a table having both partitioning and bucketing in hive ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
Partitioning is you data is divided into number of directories on HDFS. Each directory is a partition. For example, if your table definition is like

```
CREATE TABLE user_info_bucketed(user_id BIGINT, firstname STRING, lastname STRING)
COMMENT 'A bucketed copy of user_info'
PARTITIONED BY(ds STRING)
CLUSTERED BY(user_id) INTO 256 BUCKETS;
```

Then you'll have directories on hdfs like

```
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-11/
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-12/
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-13/
```

Bucketing is about how your data is distributed inside a partition, So you'll have files on hdfs like

```
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-11/000000_0
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-11/000000_1
...
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-11/000000_255
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-12/000000_0
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-12/000000_1
...
/user/hive/warehouse/user_info_bucketed/ds=2011-01-12/000000_255
```

Reference:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables
http://www.hadooptpoint.com/hive-buckets-optimization-techniques/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.This is straight forward.
try something below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee_partition_bucket
( 
employeeID Int,
firstName String,
designation String,
salary Int
) 
PARTITIONED BY (department string)
CLUSTERED BY (designation) INTO 2 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

In this example I Have created partition by **department** and bucket by **designation**
Hopw this will help you

Comment: How data will be distributed in the Filesystem directory? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

you can !! In that case, you will be having buckets inside partitioned data !